# why does the area "inside" the graph of $y=\frac{\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}{\sin x}$ look like a circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[image]

I decided to graph this ratio because both functions have to do with circles and thought the graph may look interesting, but I can't connect the dots.

Comment: Plot just $1/\sin x$ and zoom in the y direction. Since $|\sin x|\le 1$, you will notice that there is nothing in the $-1$ to $1$ range. Then you just multiply $1$ by the $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, which is the $y$ component of the circle.

Comment: @Andrei , I get it now, thanks. You can write this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Just a bonus thing I noticed as well, judging from @Andrei's answer, I figured that $y=\sin x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ will yield a similar result but with the circular area being shaded inside the circle instead of outside, and it did! Try it if you haven't already

Comment: Similar to amplitude modulated  time signal in Communications technology using high frequency $1/\sin x$ as multiplication factor with low frequency circle variation  of signal $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. The lower envelope is of lower frequency can be seen as a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot just $1/\sin x$ and zoom in the $y$ direction. Since $|\sin x|\le1$, you will notice that there is nothing in the $−1$ to $1$ range. Then you just multiply $1$ by the $\sqrt{r^2−x^2}$, which is the $y$ component of the circle.